# Opinion based? No, just quite difficult

Tags: discussion, support, specific-question, close-reasons

This question has been tagged "opinion based": [Would it be much safer to have to have an airplane inspected twice a year?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/16346/would-it-be-much-safer-to-have-to-have-an-airplane-inspected-twice-a-year?rq=1)

I believe it is not opinion based and it could even lead to very interesting answers if someone can find the data to answer it.

It is "just" a matter of finding how the **failure rate of aircrafts** changes in relation to **time from from last inspection**. This data may be hard to find but I don't feel it's an opinion.

How can (if it should) be edited to fit?

Ps: I say very interesting because it is entirely possible that failure rates of aircrafts post-inspection is a *bathtub curve* thus leading to the conclusion that inspections done at some (obviously extreme) rate is more dangerous than less inspection.

Comment: I modified the referenced question so that it is explicitly requesting data rather than opinions.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I agree that asking for data would be an improvement and it's probably a good general way to improve 'fuzzy' questions and make them more focused and answerable. In this case, asking for data or research on how/if failures are correlated with maintenance frequency might get a better response. Whether you want to edit the existing question or open a new one is really up to you.

(You might find [this article](https://www.savvyaviation.com/wp-content/uploads/articles_eaa/EAA_2011-03_the-waddington-effect.pdf) interesting, BTW.)

Comment: Very interesting! Thankyou! :-)